# spring boot .crt and keystore files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm hoping that somebody can give me some advice on this, I've inherited a few projects that use spring-boot and attempt to secure the application with keystore and cert files these are stored in the :resources/resources/*.crt folder.

The app uses libraries that have been created again by others which attempt to load up these .crt files when SB starts up, they (the libraries) have default values injected which point to the correct location (above) the issue that I have is that SB fails start up as it cannot find the path or the file specified, does anybody have any ideas where to go with this.

Edit;-

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t2XX.png)

Many thanks for any guiding lights.

Comment: Could you share the code and error codes as well?

Comment: Sharing the code is a bit difficult as you can imagine, this is not a personal project. I'll add in the file structure though maybe that will shine a light on the issue.